# How do I install Splunklib for Python 3.7 on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.7, splunk, pycrypto, pycryptodome

`Splunklib` for `Python 3.7` fails to install on my Windows machine. 
Since `pycrypto` was not ported to `Python 3`, I've uninstalled it and installed `pycrypodome` as replacement. 
Unfortunately, when trying to install `splunklib`, `pip` still tries to install `pycrypto`.

```
*Installing collected packages: pycrypto, splunklib
Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... *
```

Is there a way to force `Python` or `pip` to use `pycryptodome` instead of `pycrypto`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found the way to install it:

1. Uninstall `pycrypto`
   `pip uninstall pycrypto`
2. Install pycryptodome as replacement of pycypto
   `pip install pycryptodome`
3. Install splunklib without dependencies
   `pip install splunklib --no-deps`
4. Edit "pythonlib"\splunklib-1.0.0.dist-info\METADATA and
   replace "Requires-Dist: pycrypto" with "Requires-Dist: pycryptodome"
5. install splunk-sdk
   `pip install splunk-sdk`
6. check that everything is ok
   `pip install splunklib`

Comment: You aught to select this as the correct answer - use the tick underneath the voting buttons.

Comment: Also, splunklib is deprecated.

Comment: Done, thanks for the reminder. 
Yes, splunklib is deprecated. I then realized that the code I wanted to port to python 3 was importing splunklib and splunklib.client but was only using the second one, which comes from splunk-sdk lib. 
Removing "import splunklib" also worked in my case ...
The above can however be useful for folks who need to use the deprecated splunklib.
Thanks for the feedback

Comment: For more info regarding point no 4 - review this in your env variable like in my case myproject\my_env\Lib\site-packages\splunklib-1.0.0.dist-info\METADATA  update this  file ....  #Requires-Dist: pycrypto
"Requires-Dist: pycryptodome"

Comment: step 4 still unclear to me. How do you find where pip would place this? I used the command `pip cache dir`, and it is not in the directory listed by that.